# Error running pod install when building iOS app (Flutter)

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

I started having this error when trying to run my app (flutter run). This only happens for iOS.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             387ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Finding Podfile changes
      M path_provider_foundation
      M shared_preferences_foundation
      - Flutter
      - cloud_firestore
      - firebase_auth
      - firebase_core
      - flutter_native_splash
      - google_sign_in_ios

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
    cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '10.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.10.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_native_splash` from
    `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_native_splash/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `google_sign_in_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in_ios/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_foundation` from
    `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_foundation/darwin`
    -> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_foundation` from
    `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_foundation/darwin`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is
      only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_4_2_c.txt exists! Returning local because
      checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/3.0.0/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json exists!
      Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because
      checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.11.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists!
      Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_6_1_e.txt exists! Returning local because
      checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/1/e/nanopb/2.30909.0/nanopb.podspec.json exists! Returning
      local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_d_4_0.txt exists! Returning local because
      checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/d/4/0/GoogleSignIn/7.0.0/GoogleSignIn.podspec.json exists!
      Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists!
      Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Firestore":
      In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
        Firebase/Firestore (= 10.3.0)

      In Podfile:
        cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 4.8.1, which
        depends on
          Firebase/Firestore (= 10.10.0)


    You have either:
     * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install
     --repo-update`.
     * changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/Firestore` inside your development pod
     `cloud_firestore`.
       You should run `pod update Firebase/Firestore` to apply changes you've made.

    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:
    317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:
    299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:
    297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:
    257:in `process_topmost_state'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:
    182:in `resolve'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43
    :in `resolve'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:9
    4:in `resolve'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/ana
    lyzer.rb:1082:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interfac
    e.rb:64:in `section'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/ana
    lyzer.rb:1080:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/ana
    lyzer.rb:125:in `analyze'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:
    422:in `analyze'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:
    244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interfac
    e.rb:64:in `section'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:
    243:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:
    162:in `install!'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command/insta
    ll.rb:52:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in
    `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52
    :in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top
    (required)>'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
  pod repo update



Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

Can anyone help me with this? I have been stuck here for quite some time already. I'm also quite new to developing with Flutter so would appreciate detailed instructions.

Already tried pod repo update, as well as other solutions I found online such as flutter clean and pub get but they did not work

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the Podflie.lock file and the Pods directory in ios directory of your project.
2. Install a new pod file in ios directory

`$ cd ios`

`$ pod install --repo-update`

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the Podflie.lock file and the Pods directory in ios directory of your project.
2. set platform :ios, '10.0' to platform :ios, 'higher version' in the Podfile.

   **ex: platform :ios, '13.0'**
3. run below command

> $ cd ios

> $ pod install --repo-update

It worked fine for me. Happy coding .